# How to build a single array of results from cakePHP containable behavior find?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

`Models: User, Product`, both `ActAs Containable`.

`User hasMany Produc`t and `Prodct BelongsTo User`

Results after `User->find('all')`:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Paul'
        ),
        'Product' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '7',
                'user_id' => '1',
                'price' => '100'
                ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                  'id' => '9',
                   'user_id' => '1',
                   'price' => '10'
                    )
            ),
(int) 1 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '2'
            'name' => 'Susan'
        ),
        'Product' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '8',
                'user_id' => '2',
                 'price' => '22'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                    'id' => '10',
                    'user_id' => '2',
                    'price' => '15'
                    )
      )
);
```

I want to show only the `Products`, order by `price`ASC (independent of user order), but I will need some `User` info for my views.

Eg. of view:

"Product with ID = 9 belongs to Paul and costs 10"
"Product with ID = 10 belongs to Susan and costs 15"
"Product with ID = 8 belongs to Susan and costs 22"
"Prodcut with ID = 7 belongs to Paul and costs 100

Comment: If you want to only show the Products, why are your running the find from the User model? Did you try running `find` on the Product model? Otherwise, if you want to manipulate your array, you should read up on the [Hash class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html)

Comment: @AgRizzo, if run `find` from Product model, how can I have in my view/prints user info ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are currently running the `find` from the User model and getting Product information. Why would you think running the `find` from the Product would not return User information? You set up the model associations in both directions. You need to run the `find` from the Product model, look at the results and determine if they meet your need.

Comment: Im now running `find` from `Products` model and the results are an array with products, no `User` informations attached, only the `user_id` foreing key ofc

Comment: @AgRizzo, Take a look to the query I want to be done: `SELECT User.username, Product.id, Product.user_id, Product.price FROM ddb.products AS Product, ddb.users AS User WHERE User.id = Product.user_id ORDER BY Product.price ASC`

Comment: That, using find("") method is possible

Answer (score 0):

Solution was put `contain` to `false` and create a custom join:

```
return $this->Product->find('all', array(
    'contain' => false,
    'joins' => array (
        array (
        'table' => 'users',
        'alias' => 'User',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array (
            'User.id = Product.user_id'
        )
    )
    ),
    'fields' => array('User.*', 'Product.*'),
    'order' => 'Product.year ASC'           
    ));
```

But, im wondering if there is a better aproach!

In `model` `Product` i've tried with `contain` => array('User') but an error occurr "The User model is not associated to Product model" which i didnt understood cause I got the $hasMany and $BelongsTo well defined.

Comment: `public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $BelongsTo = array('User');`

Comment: Variable names are case-sensitive. You need to use `$belongsTo` _(notice the lowercase "b")_